# Pg gem not installing with latest ruby i.e. 3.0.2

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, pg

Requirement: We have a script that performs a certain action in PG Db which is written in Ruby 1.8.7 now the requirement is to update the ruby version to the latest. This script uses many gems we are able to install all expect for following:
require 'pg'
require 'dbd/pg'

Action Done Till Now: While the other gems were installed successfully any effort in trying to install PG-related gems failed even we have tried to install the old PG version but getting errors every time.
After researching a while we found that the latest rvm installer doesn't have support for PG.

Question: So is it that we cannot update the Ruby version with this script? or are there any other PG-supported gems are present.

PS: We have very limited knowledge of Ruby and before this, we never worked on it.

Comment: **"getting errors every time"** - What errors? We need to know what you're seeing in  order to answer the question.

Comment: Also: I would not advise making the quantum leap from ruby 1.8.7 to 3.0.2 in one go!! Those versions were released **over 18 years apart**, so it's inevitable there are many compatibility changes in that time period.

Comment: *Also*, since ruby 3.0 is a major change, some libraries are still catching up to regain full compatibility. It's possible that a gem you're trying to use isn't yet fully compatible -- so it might be better to use ruby 2.7 for now? *For example*, I see there's [this open issue for `pg`](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/392), but I don't know if that's applicable to you, because you didn't show us the error message.

Comment: @TomLord Here is the error: Error: Unable to load driver 'pg' (underlying error: wrong constant name pg).